# Foreach over all listViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I wrote a listView

```
<ListView 
  SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged" 
  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
  Background="Transparent" 
  x:Name="uiListView" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" 
  Width="117" 
  Height="Auto"
  BorderThickness="0" 
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

And bind it to

```
public class ListImage
{
    public ListImage(string cover, string title, string isvideo)
    {
        Cover = cover;
        Title = title;
        isVideo = isvideo;

    }

    public string Cover { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string isVideo { get; set; }
}
```

Im adding items this way:

```
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "false"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "true"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "false"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "true"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "false"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "true"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "false"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "true"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "false"));
uiListView.Items.Add(new ListImage(@"C:\tablet\3kings_full.jpg", @"Title", "true"));
```

Everything's nice. I now need to access ListViewItem of clicked element so

```
private void MySelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(uiListView.Items[uiListView.SelectedIndex].GetType().ToString());
}
```

But this returns me ListImage type instead of ListViewItem. How can i access it?

Best Regards

Comment: This is how WPF works, what exactly do you want to access if it's not the ListImage?

Comment: What is it you want to do with the listViewItem? There's probably another way to do achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator` or, more likely, change your approach. You can likely use the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` property to set up properties on the `ListBoxItem` that you need.

Answer (score 0):

user1697180, I wonder if you come from a WinForms background?

WPF is far more decalarative, at least in the XAML and I found that in making the switch, you have to think of things differently.

I note that you are have both bound to an items source, AND then you are supplying items individually. The items source is supposed to be your collection of items, so you don't need to add them to the Items as well.

Also, you usually use some property on your item that is bound to whatever property it is that you want on your listViewItem, so you never need to access the item itself.